# Can I force controller to reload some data when people hit back button even on the same route in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In my angular app, this is my route pattern:

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/DocumentUploader/folder/:folderid?', {
        templateUrl: '/FileManagers/views/items.html',
        controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'items'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/DocumentUploader/folder'
    });
```

When the page loads, the default route is:
http://localhost:5460/Workbenchv2.cshtml#/DocumentUploader/folder

So this will go to the root folder.

Then user can click a folder name, and the route changes to 
http://localhost:5460/Workbenchv2.cshtml#/DocumentUploader/folder/92E39760-156D-4C62-A295-E4D1C20706CD (internal ID for the folder)

Now if user hit the back button, angular will not reload the controller (as it is the same route), so I can't refresh my data.

Is it possible to force angularjs to reload the controller, even if the route is the same?

Comment: Is the `folderid` optional?

Comment: you can tell from the route folderid?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or code sample? I've tried to reproduce the problem but in my case it's working. Please look at my posted answer and let me know whether it solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a Plunker here: [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gNxC2fKWwOnWKwcluaan?p=preview)

In my case when user click the back button, the controller is reloaded. Here is the controller that I'm using:

```
myApp.controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
  function($scope, $routeParams){
    var folderId = $routeParams.folderid;

    if(!folderId){
      $scope.msg = 'You are in root folder';
    } else {
      $scope.msg = 'You are in folderId=' + folderId;
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Happy to know your problem is solved! You may consider accepting my answer if it helped you to figure out the problem :)